# long function split in multiple line to combin with VBA macro not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function on excel that searches all of the tabs of a workbook for a specific value and return a date on another workbook. Now I am trying to combine that function with a VBA macro I have developed. Because the function I am using is searching through many tabs, I had to break it down to many lines.

to explain a bit the function, I am using a if that checks whether using iserror() and vlookup() to find an email through tabs of a workbook. if it finds it returns a date. If not the runs another if with the same characteristics as the first one. Same again if it finds the email at the 2nd tab, writes a date and if not runs another until all of the tabs have been searched

From searching around I found that I must use " _ " in order for the command to be continued in a line below and that the " _ " must not be in within a string.

I had developed 3 different codes.

1st try

```
> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
>         "=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week1 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""6/11/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week2 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""13/11/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week3 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""20/11/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week4  [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""27/11/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week5 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""4/12/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week6 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""11/12/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week7 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""18/12/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week8  [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""25/12/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week9[EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""1/1/2018"" ," & _
> "IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week9[EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""1/1/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week10[EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""8/1/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week11 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""15/1/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week12 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""22/1/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week13 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""29/1/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week14 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""5/2/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week15 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""12/2/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week16 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""19/2/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week17 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""26/2/2018"" ," & _
> "IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week18[EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""5/3/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week19 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""12/3/2018"" ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week20 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""19/3/2018"" ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week21 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""26/3/2018"" ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week22 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""2/4/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week23 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""9/4/2018""  ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week24 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""16/4/2018"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week025 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""23/4/2018"" ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week26 [EmailAddress],1,FALSE))),""30/4/2018"", ""Something is Wrong""))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

When run I have a run-time error 1004

2nd Try

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week1 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""6/11/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week2 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""13/11/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week3 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""20/11/2017"" ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week4  [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""27/11/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week5 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""4/12/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week6 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""11/12/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week7 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""18/12/2017"" ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week8  [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""25/12/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week9 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""1/1/2018"" , & _
        IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week9 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""1/1/2018"",  IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week10[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""8/1/2018""  , IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week11[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""15/1/2018""  ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week12 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""22/1/2018"" , IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week13[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""29/1/2018"",  IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week14[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""5/2/2018"",  IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week15[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""12/2/2018"" , IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week16[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""19/2/2018""  ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week17 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""26/2/2018"" , & _
        IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week18[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""5/3/2018"",  IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week19[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""12/3/2018"" , IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week20[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""19/3/2018""  ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week21 [Email Address],1,FALSE))),""26/3/2018"" , IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week22[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""2/4/2018"",  IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week23[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""9/4/2018""  , IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week24[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""16/4/2018""  ,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week025[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""23/4/2018"" , IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week26[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""30/4/2018"", ""Something is Wrong"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

Its similar code as above but without the brackets at the end and start of each line and the result is an unexpected end of statement.

3rd Try

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week1[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""06/11/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week2[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""13/11/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week3[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""20/11/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week4[Email Address],1,FALSE)))," & _
    """27/11/2017"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week5[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""04/12/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week6[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""11/12/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week7[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""18/12/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week8[Email Address],1,FALSE)))," & _
    """25/12/2017"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week9[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""01/01/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week9[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""08/01/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week10[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""15/01/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week11[Email Address],1,FALSE)))," & _
    """22/01/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week12[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""29/01/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week13[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""05/02/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week14[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""12/02/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week15[Email Address],1,FALSE)))," & _
    """19/02/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week16[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""16/02/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week17[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""05/03/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week18[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""12/03/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week19[Email Address],1,FALSE)))," & _
    """19/03/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week20[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""26/03/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week21[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""02/04/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week22[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""09/04/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week23[Email Address],1,FALSE))), & _
    """16/04/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week24[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""23/04/2018"", IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DataExtract.xlsx!Week025[Email Address],1,FALSE))),""30/04/2018"","" ""))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

This code seems to be the best of the three but the error message is  " Compiler error : Syntax Error"

I know that the functions works correctly because I have tried it on a single cell. On the third attempt, I tried to automatically record it as macro.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: @pnuts I just tried it using the 2nd try and I still get the compile error: Expected: End of statement and highlights the start of the second line

Comment: Indeed I was sort of 1 closing parenthesis in 2nd try but still the same error message. I will update my question and add an explanation of the nested vlookup function I am using

Comment: yep, you are right, Excel auto recorder messed up with the command and the moment I correct the command I get a compile error: Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that to make the formula simpler you could set up a separate sheet called, say "INDEX", which has references to the email address column of all the different weeks using this formula `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Week" & COLUMN()&"!B"&ROW()),"")` (where column B contains the email addresses). So all the email addresses in week 1 are in column 1, for week 2 in column 2, etc. Make this area a named range, say EmailsTable. Use this UDF:

```
    Public Function WeekNumber(sEmail As String) As Variant
    '// Finds the column number (i.e. week number) of the first
    '// occurrence of the given email address in the EmailsTable
    '// If not found returns zero
        Dim oFound As Range


        Set oFound = [EmailsTable].Find(sEmail, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext)

        If oFound Is Nothing Then
            WeekNumber = 0

        Else

            WeekNumber = oFound.Column

        End If

    End Function
```

This UDF will return the week number in which the first occurrence of the given email occurs. In a separate part of the INDEX sheet set up a list of the 26 dates corresponding to each sheet and name the list, say, "DateList". Then you can use a formula like this to find the date in DateList, e.g. for the email address in cell B24:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DateList,WeekNumber(B24)), "Not found")
```

or you could use VLOOKUP instead of INDEX and include an entry for week 0.